# how to convert date from one format to another in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

The request I receive contains dates in the following format:

```
<CreatedDate>08/24/2014 21:53:14</CreatedDate>
```

I need to convert the value into YYYY-MM-DD format using xslt. I can identify all "target" nodes by a certain naming pattern (they all are called somethingDate). Is there any ready-to-use syntax/function?

Comment: Assuming that you are using XSLT 1.0, the functions you have available are limited. You are limited to functions like substring() and substring-before().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this for several nodes in your input, you'd better use a named template (or a function, if you're using XSLT 2.0), for example:

```
<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="mmddyyyy"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($mmddyyyy, 7, 4)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($mmddyyyy, 1, 2)"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($mmddyyyy, 4, 2)"/>
</xsl:template>
```